# How to implement a wcf service which can host other wcf services?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have several wcf services which are hosted using ServiceHost class.
Now , I want to implement a separate wcf service which can host these services.
Anyone please suggest me how can I do it?

Suppose I have created some wcf services , I can host them by self hosting using ServiceHost , but I want that a program that can host any wcf service , so no service needs to be self hosting

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of this? You already have a WCF service hosted somewhere, so why not just use the same host for the other services?

Comment: How can a WCF service host other WCF services? That really doesn't make any sense at all.... what are you trying to accomplish? Why not just use the ServiceHost (or several hosts) to host your services?? What is that extra WCF "hosting" service intended for??

Comment: Suppose I have created some wcf services , I can host them by self hosting using ServiceHost , but I want that a program that can host any wcf service , so no service needs to be self hosting .

Comment: Ok, so you want a universal host - like IIS, but without the features. That's not a problem, but it's not a service hosting services - it's a service host hosting multiple services. Maybe one of those services is a service to administer the service host, if that's what you were thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could create a service that will host those WCF services, or host them inside IIS, I think either option would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

IIS can host your services for you - also the WAS (Windows Process Activation Server) can do the same. They both have their own pro's and cons associated with hosting.

Windows "[Dublin](http://www.microsoft.com/net/dublin.aspx)" - due out some time after .NET 4.0 - will be another step into a managed, central hosting environment for WCF services (and WF workflows).

Those all allow you to have someone else host your WCF services for you - no need for ServiceHost instances on your end of things.

Marc